# NRRD volume offset in 2D renderer

Tags: xtk

I'm just looking into a project of making a scan viewer much like Slice:Drop from the Xtk examples. I'm very new to XTK and web programming in general.

I'm using an example file of a brain, but in Slice:Drop and my own implementation (mostly borrowed from "Lesson 13: I want 2D!"), the scan comes out offset, so the image is cut off. Does anyone now how I can fix this? I was looking for a translate method or similar in the volume class, but haven't found anything useful so far.
I've tried loading this file in a couple of desktop scan loading software packages, and it loads fine (meaning centered, not cut off) there, so wondering where the problem could be.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Cheers

Edit: Just tried the same file in .nii format and that loaded fine, with the scans all centered. Maybe something strange going on with the NRRD file ...

[image]